# delphi get hour&minutes difference in specific format

Tags: delphi

Was playing with dateutils and did some experimenting.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fromDate, toDate : TDateTime;
begin
  fromDate := cxDateEdit1.Date ;
  toDate   := cxDateEdit2.Date ;
  Label1.Caption := 'Hour difference   '+IntToStr(HoursBetween(toDate, fromDate))+'   hours';
  Label2.Caption := 'Minute difference   '+IntToStr(MinutesBetween(toDate, fromDate))+'   minutes';
  end;
```

How can I get a time difference result in a label caption like hh/mm (example 01:05) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SysUtils.FormatDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) has many useful `TDateTime` to string conversions:

```
Label3.Caption := 'Time difference [hh:mm] '+FormatDateTime('hh:nn',toDate-fromDate);
```

---

As an alternative, use the result from `MinutesBetween`:

```
var
  minutes: Integer;
...
minutes := MinutesBetween(toDate,FromDate);
Label3.Caption := 
  'Time difference [hh:mm] '+Format('%.2d:%.2d',[minutes div 60,minutes mod 60]);
```

Comment: The second approach has the benefit of not chopping off the hours at 24

Comment: Well, the first part does not work properly as the diff in one day (24 hours) displays 00:00. Second one does.

Answer (score 4):

A `TDateTime` is intended to be used with absolute dates and times. Instead you might consider `TTimeSpan` from the `System.TimeSpan` unit.

```
uses
  System.TimeSpan;

....

var
  d1, d2: TDateTime;
  Span: TTimeSpan;
  str: string;    

....

d1 := ...;
d2 := ...;
Span := TTimeSpan.Subtract(d2, d1);
str := Format('%.2d:%.2d', [Span.Hours, Span.Minutes]));
```

This assumes that the span is less than a day. But then the format of your output seems to build in that very assumption.

Whether or not this is really any better than simply subtracting two date time values I am not so sure.

Comment: This makes it work for more than a day: `Format('%d:%.2d', [Trunc(Span.TotalHours), Span.Minutes]));`