# Formatted time difference between two database datetime fields

Tags: delphi

I tried :

```
procedure TDataModule2.JournalLCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
JOURNAL.FieldByName('TIME').Value:= FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', JORNAL.FieldByName('end_date').AsDateTime - ZURNAL.FieldByName('start_date').AsDateTime);
end;
```

It kind of gives me the right answer at first when I run it but when I test it (change the end_date by a whole day on the sql server) then the result is totally wrong.
Any clues as to why
the oncalculate event fails?

TIME field is text.

Comment: If your time difference is 24 hours or more it cannot be formatted with hh:mm:ss.

Comment: This q needs a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In Delphi, `TDateTime` values are actually floating-point values (`Double`s) that count the number of days since 30 Dec 1899, including a fractional day. `FormatDateTime` formats *a point in time* as a string, *not* a duration. If you subtract two datetime values that are a bit more than two days apart, you might get 2.1412354, say, which might be formatted as `1900-01-01 03:23:22` using the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss`. Using `hh:nn:ss`, you naturally get `03:23:00`. What you are looking for is a way to format a *duration* in Delphi. Google will find several examples on how to do this.

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with databases, only datetime and duration formatting. It would be the same procedure if you got two dates from a file or from a web server.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40088068/12763954) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatDateTime()` is meant for formatting a specific date/time value, not a duration between two date/time values.

You can easily write your own code to format a duration, eg:

```pascal
uses
   ..., DateUtils, SysUtils;

procedure TDataModule2.JournalLCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  duration, hours, minutes, seconds: Int64;
begin
  duration := SecondsBetween(JORNAL.FieldByName('end_date').AsDateTime, ZURNAL.FieldByName('start_date').AsDateTime);

  hours := duration div 3600;
  duration := duration mod 3600;

  minutes := duration div 60;
  duration := duration mod 60;

  seconds := duration;

  JOURNAL.FieldByName('TIME').Value := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [hours, minutes, seconds]);
end;
```

Or, you can use the RTL's [`TTimeSpan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan) type to help you, eg:

```pascal
uses
   ..., System.TimeSpan, SysUtils;

procedure TDataModule2.JournalLCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  ts: TTimeSpan;
begin
  ts := TTimeSpan.Subtract(JORNAL.FieldByName('end_date').AsDateTime, ZURNAL.FieldByName('start_date').AsDateTime);
  JOURNAL.FieldByName('TIME').Value := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds]);
end;
```

Comment: If end_daate is empty then I surely get a strange reading like: 1058159:21:31

Comment: @user763539 If `SecondsBetween()` returned an `integer`, that would be able to handle durations up to ~68 years max. Sure, for short durations, that is sufficient.  But `TDateTime` covers a very large time span (Dec 30 1899 to Dec 31 9999), so once you get into hours resolution and smaller, `Intger` doesn't have enough precision to handle large time spans, hence why `Int64` is used.

Comment: @user763539 obviously, you need extra code to handle the case where `end_date` is empty. What do you expect to output when there is no `end_date` provided? If the `start_date` is not empty, then you can just use the current date/time from `SysUtils.Now()` when calculating a running duration, eg: `Fld := JORNAL.FieldByName('end_date'); if not Fld.IsNull then EndDate := Fld.AsDateTime else EndDate := Now;` And then you can do `duration := SecondsBetween(EndDate, ZURNAL.FieldByName('start_date').AsDateTime);` or `ts := TTimeSpan.Subtract(EndDate, ZURNAL.FieldByName('start_date').AsDateTime);`

Comment: I would like the TIME field to display empty if the end_date is not provided...

Comment: @user763539 so what is stopping you? If the `end_date` is empty, set the `TIME` to empty, otherwise calculate and set the `TIME` to the formatted duration, as previously shown.

Comment: ahhh ...forgot to add the 'begin' if JOURNAL.FieldByName('end_date').IsNULL  then
  JOURNAL.FieldByName('time').AsString := ''
  else   begin ...   Thank you Remy ...much obliged...